# RecyclerView scrolls to top position when change the adapter data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am doing the like and dislike for a post in a `RecyclerView`, I call the api after changing the view but the problem is that the `RecyclerView` always scrolls to the top when I notify it with the updates.

this is my adapter code :

```
 likeAnim.setOnLikeListener(object : OnLikeListener {
            override fun liked(p0: LikeButton?) {
                if (commentList[position]!!.liked) {
                    // 
 likeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_ico)
                    isLiked = false
                    callback(commentList[position], 2, layoutPosition)
                } else {
                    // likeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled_like_ico)
                    isLiked = true
                    callback(commentList[position], 1, layoutPosition)
                }
            }

            override fun unLiked(p0: LikeButton?) {
                if (commentList[position]!!.liked) {
                    // likeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_ico)
                    isLiked = false
                    callback(commentList[position], 2, layoutPosition)
                } else {
                    // likeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled_like_ico)
                    isLiked = true
                    callback(commentList[position], 1, layoutPosition)
                }
            }
        })
```

this is my activity code

```
        private fun onCommentActionSuccess(list: LikeRequestModel, type: Int, position: Int) {
    when (type) {
        1 -> Log.d("Success", "success: comment like done")
        2 -> Log.d("Success", "success: comment dislike done")
    }
    viewModel.getClassComments(LoginClass.login.user!!.data!!.school_classes_id!![0].id).observe(this@ClassHomeScreenActivity, Observer {
        when {
            it!!.isSuccess() -> onSuccessRefrech(it.data!!.data, position)
        }
    })
}

   private fun onSuccessRefrech(list: MutableList<ClasseCommentModel.Data?>, 
    position: Int) {
    Log.d("Success", "success: comment loaded")
    //initCommentAdapter(list)
    adapter.commentList = list
    // val adapter = ClassCommentsListAdapter(this@ClassHomeScreenActivity, 
      list) { it, type, pos ->
     // likeComment(it!!.id.toString(), type, pos)//Kotlin callback 
     instead of interface in java
    //  }
   // binding.postRV.swapAdapter(adapter, false)
    // adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
    binding.postRV.scrollToPosition(position)
}
```

my initAdapter function :

```
       private fun initCommentAdapter(list: 
        MutableList<ClasseCommentModel.Data?>) {
    adapter = ClassCommentsListAdapter(this@ClassHomeScreenActivity, list) { 
      it, type, position ->
        likeComment(it!!.id.toString(), type, position)//Kotlin callback 
      instead of interface in java
    }
    binding.postRV.setHasFixedSize(true) // 
    binding.postRV.itemAnimator = null // remove recycle view animation
    binding.postRV.layoutManager = 
     LinearLayoutManager(this@ClassHomeScreenActivity, 
      OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false)
    binding.postRV.adapter = adapter
      }
```

my callback function :

```
       private fun likeComment(commentId: String, type: Int, position: Int) {
    when (type) {
        1 -> {
            viewModel.likeComment(commentId).observe(this@ClassHomeScreenActivity, Observer {
                when {
                    it!!.isError() -> onErrorAction(it.error)
                    it.isSuccess() -> onCommentActionSuccess(it.data!!, type, position)
                }
            })
        }
        2 -> {
            viewModel.dislikeComment(commentId).observe(this@ClassHomeScreenActivity, Observer {
                when {
                    it!!.isError() -> onErrorAction(it.error)
                    it.isSuccess() -> onCommentActionSuccess(it.data!!, type, position)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

private fun onCommentActionSuccess(list: LikeRequestModel, type: Int, 
position: Int) {
    when (type) {
        1 -> Log.d("Success", "success: comment like done")
        2 -> Log.d("Success", "success: comment dislike done")
    }



 viewModel.getClassCommentsSingleEvent
 (LoginClass.login.user!!.data!!.school_clas 
  ses_id!![0].id).observe(this@ClassHomeScreenActivity, Observer {
        when {
            it!!.isSuccess() -> onSuccessRefrech(it.data!!.data, position)
        }
    })
}
```

I wanna stay in the scroll position without scrolling to top

Comment: i did it but always scroll to top

Comment: what are u doing in your callback function

Comment: @Shaon i add the code on the top check it please

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

1. Don't use multiple objects of adapter. Use only single object and try to update the data. Don't set adapter again after updating data.
2. After updating list just calling `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` will solve your problem.

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: yeah i use only one adapter

Answer (score 1):

Views need to have an id in order for them to save their state, so make sure all parent layouts of your RecyclerViews have an id.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem but I was having the same issue and it was because I was calling setAdapter after notify. So, not calling setAdapter after notify solved the problem.

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(mAdapter.getItemCount(), list.size() - 1);
```

`recyclerView.setAdapter();` // remove this line. 
//Do this only when you're setting the data for the first time or when adapter is null.